# Unknown Command "syncdb" when calling from an external exe file made by pyinstaller

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, syncdb

I have a folder named db

db
    ------ `__init__.py`
    ------ `dbobject.py`
    ------ `models.py`
    ------ `settings.py`

inside `__init__.py`

```
from django.conf import settings

def syncdb():
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "db.settings")
    from django.core.management import call_command
    call_command('syncdb', interactive=False)
```

Then i had installed this db folder using python distutils in site-packages.

Now i am having another folder named **cron** contains:

- main.py
- settings.py

settings.py

```
from db import syncdb
syncdb()
```

Here it works.

Then made an executable of main.py

After running main.exe it gives me error:

`django.core.management.CommandError: Unknown Command: 'syncdb'`

Comment: syncdb maybe should run in project folder,so try to include all files togother in main.exe

Comment: I need to share same db folder with lot of other scripts thats why i have putted that separately.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the working dir to your project folder before running your `syncdb` function:

```
import os
from db import syncdb

os.chdir(path_to_your_project) # Change working dir.
syncdb()
```